# Evaluating $\int x^2 \sqrt{1-x^2}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I hope I can find a way to integrate this formula without resorting to numerical techniques.

\begin{equation}
\int x^2 \sqrt{1-x^2}\ dx
\end{equation}

I am not sure if there's actually a closed form for this or not?
I tried integration by parts, but it seems not working! Here's my last resort before numerical solutions.

Comment: Integration by parts should yield a closed form. Let $$u=x^2\implies du=2xdx\ \text{and}\ dv=\sqrt{1-x^2}dx.$$ For $\int dv$ you must then use the trigonometric substitution of $x=\sin\theta$. You will then need to integrate by parts again because you will arrive at $\int \arcsin(x)dx.$

Comment: Generally when people speak of "numerical solutions" they are talking about definite integrals.

Comment: @fruitegg There is no need for substitution in this problem. Just integrate by parts and work out terms. One will end up with $\int 1/\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx$ that will give an arcsin, though.

Comment: @mickep, I see your point, but isn't integration by parts, by definition, a form of substitution? It's traditionally expressed as $\int udv=uv-\int vdu$, implying that you must substitute in for both $u$ and $v$ (and this is the exact substitution I was referring to).

Comment: @fruitegg No. Integration by parts is not substitution. Integration by parts is moving derivatives from one function to another. It is used for various things. In this context, mostly to simplify integration.

Comment: @GFauxPas, In my bigger problem this is a definite integral which I would have used a numerical solution for if I reached desperation. You're right, that's why I didn't write the limits here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

Try substitution $x=\sin\theta\longrightarrow dx=\cos\theta\ d\theta$, then you will get

\begin{align}
\int\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta\ d\theta&=\int\left(\frac{\sin2\theta}{2}\right)^2\ d\theta\\[10pt]
&=\frac{1}{4}\int\sin^22\theta\ d\theta\\[10pt]
&=\frac{1}{4}\int\left(\frac{1-\cos4\theta}{2}\right)\ d\theta\\[10pt]
\end{align}

Comment: That was so obvious, I am silly . 
Thank you Sophie.  
I think in the last line, you meant to write $cos4\theta$, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with integration by parts and rearranging terms:

First, integrating by parts and adding and subtracting a $1$ in the numerator,
$$
\begin{aligned}
I=\int x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx & = \frac{x^3}{3}\sqrt{1-x^2}+\int\frac{x^3}{3}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx\\
&=\frac{x^3}{3}\sqrt{1-x^2}-\int\frac{x^3}{3}\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx+\int\frac{x^3}{3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx.
\end{aligned}
$$
We got $I$ back in the right-hand side, and moving it to the left-hand side, we find
$$
I=\frac{x^3}{4}\sqrt{1-x^2}+\int\frac{1}{4}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx.\tag{1}
$$
We can continue from $(1)$ in two ways. Adding and subtracting a $1$ in the numerator, we get
$$
I=\frac{x^3}{4}\sqrt{1-x^2}-\frac{1}{4}\int\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx+\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx\tag{2}
$$
If we instead integrate by parts, we get
$$
I=\frac{x^3}{4}\sqrt{1-x^2}-\frac{1}{4}x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\frac{1}{4}\int\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx.\tag{3}
$$
We add $(2)$ and $(3)$, and find that
$$
2I=\frac{x^3}{2}\sqrt{1-x^2}-\frac{1}{4}x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx,
$$
and hence, finally,
$$
\begin{aligned}
I&=\frac{x^3}{4}\sqrt{1-x^2}-\frac{1}{8}x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx\\
&=\frac{x^3}{4}\sqrt{1-x^2}-\frac{1}{8}x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\frac{1}{8}\arcsin x+C.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I used Sophie's answer and I verified by yours. I am sorry I can't '+1' here yet.

Comment: Do as you please. Since you actually have limits (not stated in the original question), the method of Sophie Agnesi might fit better. If one must change back the coordinate to $x$, then it might be more tedious.